# Why will my Singleton StartUp EJB not injected or found in my Stateful Bean?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb

I have 4 EJBs:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@Local
public class TelegramTable {

@Startup
@Local
@Singleton
public class TelegramQueue extends GenericBean {

@Singleton
@Startup
@Local
public class JsonGatewayClient extends GenericBean implements GatewayClient {
```

and

```
@Stateful
@Local
public class ScannerHandler implements GatewayClient {
```

I can successfully inject **TelegramTable** and **TelegramQueue** into the **JsonGatewayClient** object or into the **ScannerHandler** object.

But if try to Inject the **JsonGatewayClient** into the **ScannerHandler** then i have the following Exception in my server.log:

```
[2015-09-18T20:25:15.077+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1442600715077] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=de.topmedicare.websocket.ScannerHandler/jsonGatewayClient,Local 3.x interface =de.topmedicare.websocket.JsonGatewayClient,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session]]

[2015-09-18T20:25:15.077+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1442600715077] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [mes-ear]]]

[2015-09-18T20:25:15.077+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1442600715077] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=de.topmedicare.websocket.ScannerHandler/jsonGatewayClient,Local 3.x interface =de.topmedicare.websocket.JsonGatewayClient,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ComponentValidator.accept(ComponentValidator.java:374)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:409)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbDescriptor.visit(EjbDescriptor.java:2823)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbDescriptor.visit(EjbDescriptor.java:2811)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:115)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:621)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.visit(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:757)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:116)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:621)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.validate(ApplicationArchivist.java:703)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:248)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:232)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:188)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:222)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:878)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:818)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:374)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:396)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor135.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:165)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2015-09-18T20:25:15.081+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1442600715081] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [mes-ear] : Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=de.topmedicare.websocket.ScannerHandler/jsonGatewayClient,Local 3.x interface =de.topmedicare.websocket.JsonGatewayClient,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session]]
```

The message in the server.log suggest that the **JsonGatewayClient** EJB is not found, but the **TelegramTable** object is found. And the setup-ups of **TelegramTable** and **JsonGatewayClient** is the same.... (*Singleton*, *StartUp*, *Local*)

Dont know if it is important: Using Glassfish 4.0

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If i use

```
@EJB(beanName = "JsonGatewayClient")
GatewayClient jsonGatewayClient;
```

in the **ScannerHandler** than it works.
It seems that i **must** use the **GatewayClient** Interface. (Maybe someone can explain why?)

Regards,
jo

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the EJB 3 container relies on conventions and injects the one and only existing EJB 3 implementation. It is convenient because in vast majority of all cases you only have one single implementation of an interface. Because it is the only possible choice, additional configuration doesn't provide any added value. It wouldn't be DRY.

But if you get an additional implementation of the interface - this approach will break.

```
@Local
public interface Service {

    public String getMessage();
}

@Stateless
public class DefaultService implements Service {

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello from: " + this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

Any additional implementation of the service breaks the Dependency Injection through convention.

```
@Stateless
public class SpecificService implements Service {
     public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello from: " + this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

Now you have two choices how to fix that problem:
1.) using annotations:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class AnnotatedClient {
    // define the service to use here (static)
    @EJB(beanName="DefaultService")
    private Service service;

    public String getHello() {
        return this.service.getMessage();
    }
}
```

2.) using XML configuration file in the ejb-jar.xml:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class XMLClient {

    @EJB
    private Service service;

    public String getHello() {
        return this.service.getMessage();
    }
}
```

and an XML config file defining the implementation to use in

```
<ejb-name>XMLClientBean</ejb-name>
    <ejb-local-ref>
       <ejb-ref-name>com.example.XMLClientBean/service</ejb-ref-name>
           <local>com.example.service.Service</local>
           <ejb-link>DefaultService</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
```

hope that helps